# Why does input for sort in awk has to be piped?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Just a short one for the understanding of awk:
why does

`awk '{split ($4,a,".");print $1,$2,$3,a[1]|"sort -nk3 "}'`

work (and **sort by the third column**, as it is supposed to be), whereas this one

`awk '{split ($4,a,".");print $1,$2,$3,a[1];"sort -nk3 "}'`

does not? I expected that `sort` processes the output from the previous command anyway, **with or without a pipe**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
awk '{split ($4,a,".");print $1,$2,$3,a[1]; "sort -nk3 "}'
```

there is no sort, just an no op string with contents "sort ..",  `print >` or `print |` invokes different behavior with interacting the shell.  Note that you can pipe it outside of `awk` as well.

```
awk '{split ($4,a,"."); print $1,$2,$3,a[1]}' | sort -nk3
```

will work fine.

**tldr;** use pipe to invoke sort

Comment: does this mean awk itself has no sort function and we are borrowing it from the shell?

Comment: originally didn't, now has `asort` but not as flexible as the shell's sort.